# Stereoscopic capture (2 cameras) on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, camera, raspicam, compute-module

What's the best way to connect 2 cameras to the Raspberry Pi? Is it true the only way to do it is with the compute module?

1. Can you use 2 USB cameras?
2. Can you use a multi-camera adapter like this? (https://www.ebay.com/i/261942396199?chn=ps)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of options here but like anything else it depends on your use case.  To have true simultaneous image capture you would need to have multiple pi’s.  There is an interesting product called [the cluster hat](https://clusterhat.com) that will connect up to 4 zeros as a cluster and allows them to be controlled by a single Pi3.

[here is a really cool example from the_anykey on instructables pulling together multiple cameras to create a 3D scan](https://www.google.com/amp/www.instructables.com/id/Multiple-Raspberry-PI-3D-Scanner/%3Famp_page%3Dtrue).  This is done over Ethernet with a control pi node to trigger all the slave pi’s simultaneously.

To accomplish multi image capture on a single Pi, the multi-camera adapter doesn’t give you multiple video streams but instead multiplexes the camera output taking a still from one then a still from another.  This would work fine if frame rate is not an issue.  For instance if you were scanning a static object.

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: what is the timing max difference for cluster for all images, how far apart are they?

Comment: @bakalolo It depends on a couple of things including how fast the scene is changing.  With a static scene, the acquisition speed doesn’t matter and the difference between images should be zero.  The faster the scene changes the faster you will need to capture images to get accurate results.  The accuracy needs should also factor in.  The less the requirement for accuracy, the slower the frame rate that can be tolerated.  Commercially available tracking systems range from 60 Hz to 300Hz (30-150 per camera).